# RTF Template for my custom report not printing complete rows

Tags: rtf

I have this BI report I am generating using an RTF template. I am using an XML data that has 2 columns exported from my data model directly. However, when I try to preview my report using the XML data I exported, it only prints 1 row.

I am already grouped them (repeating group functionality) but still encountering the issue.